# How can I get file path in mac ox system?

Tags: macos

How can I get the selected file or folder path in Mac OS System?

In Linux, I can just easily use "Ctrl + L" to copy the file path, however, in Mac OS System, I can not do the same thing.

Are there also some similar shortcuts in mac system?

Comment: This question belongs to Ask Different.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a `bash` function like this:

```
################################################################################
# Get path of file selected in Finder
################################################################################
getsel() {
osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder" to return POSIX path of first item of (get selection as alias list)
EOF
}
```

---

If you have **Finder** and **Terminal** open, you can also drag a file from **Finder** and drop it on **Terminal** window and it will paste the filename into **Terminal**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to other apps, but it works in `terminal` at least.  In the finder, you can just copy a file with CMD-C.  Then in terminal, if you paste it with CMD-V, it will paste the path to the file.

Comment: Hi Chris, this way works only in terminal...I would like to copy the path into a code editor....